# SSRS rolling up average values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Say I have a dataset called TimeManagement and an aggregated value in an SSRS report as shown in lighter blue in the image below that I want to roll up within SSRS to create a sum total.

*Row Groups*

[image]

*Aggregate (Lighter Blue)*

```
=Sum(Fields!HoursMonth.Value, "Period1") / Sum(Fields!VisitsMonth.Value, "Period1")
```

*Total (Darker Blue at the bottom*

```
=Sum(Fields!HoursMonth.Value, "TimeManagement") / Sum(Fields!VisitsMonth.Value, "TimeManagement")
```

In this case I am creating an new average on the underlying data but what I really need is a sum of all the values shown in lighter blue. How do I go about achieving this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the scope of your second SUM() function to reference those values or a different group. Here's a good article from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Get the sum totals from your stored procedure and use it as a column